# Angular 9 - Property 'sanitizer' is private and only accessible within class

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 9, when run `ng serve` is give me the error:

> Property 'sanitizer' is private and only accessible within class.

My HTML Code.

```
<div class="img_wrp" *ngIf="hospital?.image">
     <img class="image-preview" [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(hospital.image)">
</div>
```

My .ts code

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor (private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

Is there something that I have miss out?

Comment: The error speaks for itself. If you want to use a property in template, you should remove the `private` keyword.

Comment: @Jared, remember that, in the .html you only can use "public" variables. So, use in constructor `constructor(public sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}` NOTE:by defect, in Angular all the variables are public